# Create a bar graph in R with multiple groups

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset with several pathogens. I want to create a bar-graph that lists the pathogens on the x-axis with 3 bars "Negative" "Positive" and "NA" (which are listed in the dataset) and count on the y-axis. I am successful in creating a bar-graph for a single pathogen with the following code, but I cannot figure out how to get all the pathogens on a single graph. Help would be appreciated.

For single pathogen:

```
countST=table(NetJoint$`sT-ETEC`)  
barplot(countST)
```

My attempt for multiple pathogens:

```
ETECcounts=table(NetJoint$`LT-ETEC`, NetJoint$`sT-ETEC`)  
barplot(ETECcounts, main="Pathogen Distribution",  
        xlab="Pathogen", beside=TRUE)
```

^^This code lists "NA", "Negative" and "Positive" on the x-axis instead of the pathogens.

Comment: welcome @katie, a good practice in stack overflow is sharing a piece of your data, then we can reproduce it. you can copy and paste the output of `dput(NetJoint)` and i think i'll be able to help you so

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share this research data

Comment: i understand.. well, i tried to answer your question.. i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It may help us if you share some of your data. But I think a solution would be something like this:

```
# create an example dataframe
NetJoint = data.frame(
  'LT-ETEC' = c('Positive', 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Positive', NA, 'Positive', NA),
  'sT-ETEC' = c(NA, 'Negative', 'Negative', NA, 'Positive', NA, 'Positive')
)
# create a table for each variable of the dataframe
ETECcounts = sapply(NetJoint, table, useNA = 'always')
# plot base layer
barplot(ETECcounts, main = 'Pathogen Distribution',  
        xlab = 'Pathogen', beside = TRUE, col = c('orange', 'darkgreen', 'grey'))
# add legend layer
legend('topright', fill = c('orange', 'darkgreen', 'grey'),
       legend = c('Positive', 'Negative', 'NA'))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!